# Chunk is called with unique data, but renders duplicate content

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Guess my problem is closely related to this one : [Snippet duplicates content when used multiple times on page](http://forums.modx.com/index.php?topic=67087.0)

The elements of my problem are the following ...

1. **$modx->loadedResources** : an (empty) array registered in the main $modx object via a snippet on page load. The array holds resource id's of the resources fetched from the DB randomly, so the same resource isn't shown twice on the same page.
2. **loadRandomResource** : a snippet using XPDO-style querying to load a random resource from the DB. It uses `$modx->parseChunk()` to fill the placeholders in the chunk with the resource data. With each call, it appends the id of the fetched resource being fetched to the `$modx->loadResources` array.

I used some debugging to check if the resource id's were properly being stored in my array, each time I fetch a new random resource, which happens to be the case. I then checked if the db returns different results, each time I call the loadRandomResource snippet, and it does. I can also confirm that it doesn't return duplicate results (I exclude the already loaded resource ID's in my XPDO query).

However, when calling the snippet at 3 various locations throughout my page template, all 3 snippet calls render the same resource, which is weird, since my debug shows that unique data is being loaded from the DB, and being sent to the chunk for rendering.

Please find below both the snippet code, as well as the chunk mark-up.
Does anyone have any ideas? Any help is much appreciated!

**loadRandomResource snippet**

```
$criteria = $modx->newQuery('modResource');
$criteria->select(array('id','pagetitle'));
$criteria->sortby('RAND()');
$criteria->limit(1);
$whereOptions = array(
    'parent' => 2,
    'deleted' => false,
    'hidemenu' => false,
    'published' => true
);
if (!empty($modx->loadedResources)) {
    $whereOptions['id:NOT IN'] = $modx->loadedResources;
}
$criteria->where($whereOptions);
$resources = $modx->getCollection('modResource', $criteria);
$output = '';
foreach ($resources as $resource) {
    $fields = $resource->toArray();
    $fields['tv.tvPersonalPicture'] = $resource->getTVValue('tvPersonalPicture');
    $fields['tv.tvJobTitle'] = $resource->getTVValue('tvJobTitle');
    $output .= $modx->parseChunk('cnkTeamListItem', $fields);
    $modx->loadedResources[] = $fields['id'];
}
return $output;
```

**cnkTeamListItem chunk**

```
<div>
    <img src="[[+tv.tvPersonalPicture]]" alt="[[+pagetitle]]" />
    <h2>[[+pagetitle]]<br /><span>[[+tv.tvJobTitle]]</span></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself, solution is a bit odd though ...

I was calling my custom snippet 3 times in my template, uncached. Each call though exactly looked the same ...

`[[!loadRandomResource? &type='teammember']]`

Even though I had the exclamation mark in place, still ModX was caching the call, within the same page request.

So when I added a random unique value to each of the 3 calls, the issue was solved.

Call 1 : `[[!loadRandomResource? &type='teammember' &unique='123465']]`

Call 2 : `[[!loadRandomResource? &type='teammember' &unique='987654']]`

Call 1 : `[[!loadRandomResource? &type='teammember' &unique='666666']]`

Don't know if this is a bug or a feature, but I thought that the exclamation mark prevented caching, both across different pageviews, as well as within the same page view. Anyhow, thx for helping.

Comment: Nice catch! I had no idea Modx does this. +1

Comment: Btw, I talked to Opengeek at Irc:
`18:32 <@opengeek> yes, if the tag signature is exactly the same, all instances will be replaced the same`
`18:32 <@opengeek> you can add something unique to the tag to get unique output`

Comment: Indeed, a unique value is required. I first wanted to write a custom snippet called "getRandValue", returning the PHP function uniqid(). But that would again not change the tag signature. I guess it is a good feature, but they should allow to enable / disable this caching approach via the setting. Now I have to add random strings everywhere manually, which looks stupid. But hey, thanks for confirming the issue / solution!

Comment: Yes it would. Opengeek even suggested something like that himself. Because Modx is parsing from the inner layer out, `[[!mysnippet &rand='[[!randSnippet]]']]` would turn into `[[!mysnippet &rand='[random value here]']]` which again would produce a unique output from `mysnippet`.

Comment: Just tried it, but it didn't work, I again get the same output threefold. As soon as I replace it with a static random string, it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for rendering chunks in snippents:

```
<?php

// get chunk or template
$tplRow = $modx->getOption('tplRow', $scriptProperties, '');

// get template
if (substr($tplRow, 0, 6) == "@CODE:") {
    $tplRow = substr($tplRow, 6);
} elseif ($chunk = $modx->getObject('modChunk', array('name' => $tplRow), true)) {
    $tplRow = $chunk->getContent();
} else {
    $tplRow = false;
}

// render template
$field = array(); // your fields
if ($tplRow) {
    $chunk = $modx->newObject('modChunk');
    $chunk->setCacheable(false);
    $chunk->setContent($tplRow);
    $output[]= $chunk->process($fields);
} else {
    $output[]= '<pre>' . print_r($fields, 1) . '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thx for your suggestion, Vasis ... I replaced mty approach with yours, and however the code itself works, it's still the same issue. The debug info shows 3 different rows from the DB getting fetched, but all three snippet calls in my template output the same data :-((

Answer (score 0):

You do realize you could have done this with getResources, don't you?

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResources

```
&sortby=`RAND()`&limit=`1`
```

Comment: Thx for your suggestion! I'm aware of getResources, but I couldn't use it here. Context is a single long page with blocks, which are filled up randomly with content. I need to keep track of already loaded resources, and exclude them from all the subsequent queries for data. So after each query, I need to retrieve the resource id, and store it in a variable, so I can add it to the list of resource ID's to exclude those from my next query. Slightly advanced, and not achievable with getResources. But thanks for your input!